# How to fix "[thread1] SyntaxError: missing } after property list"

Tags: string, mongodb

I have a String `{"count" : 364219}` and I want to insert it to mongodb collection.

I had written `db.abd.insert({"qr":"{ "count" : 364219}"})` but it is showing an error.

````
Actual result : 2019-08-02T13:25:11.920+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing } after property list @(shell):1:24

Expected result :```{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d43ec6f3f18bec3f8d31516"),
    "qr" : {
        "count" : 364219
    }
}
````

Comment: You obviously have to escape the string.

Comment: @chrispbacon even after escaping the quotes, the value would be saved as a string but it should be saved as a sub-document.

Comment: What if I can type cast the escaped string to BasicDBObject ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
db.abd.insert({"qr": JSON.parse('{"count" : 364219}')})
```